# MySQL 5.7.8 JSON merge new data

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-json

I'm trying to make a notes / comments system for an admin area with the new MySQL JSON support. Comments need to be editable and I wanted to add support for other things in the future, maybe file attachments (would store the filepath in JSON only not the file itself!).

```
    {
  "comments": [
    {
      "comment": "This is a comment",
      "user_id": 5,
      "datecreated": "2016-03-19"
    },
    {
      "comment": "This is a comment",
      "user_id": 1,
      "datecreated": "2016-03-19"
      "comments": [
        {
          "comment": "This is a sub-comment",
          "user_id": 4,
          "datecreated": "2016-03-19"
        },
        {
          "comment": "This is a sub-comment",
          "user_id": 4,
          "datecreated": "2016-03-19"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought there would be a way to merge in new data similar to array_merge() without needing to target a particular key every time.

This query works but it targets only one thing, the comment's text content. If I wanted to add/edit tags, image or file attachments etc. then I'd need a very long query or several queries.

```
UPDATE shared_notes SET json = JSON_REPLACE(json, "$.comments[1].comment", "This is a test comment") WHERE note_id = :note_id
```

I tried using JSON_REPLACE and JSON_SET functions with JSON_OBJECT but it overwrites all keys that aren't specified, which means user_id, datecreated and any sub comments get overwritten.

```
UPDATE shared_notes SET json = JSON_REPLACE(json, "$.comments[1]", JSON_OBJECT("comment", "This is a test comment") ) WHERE note_id = :note_id
```

This frankenstein of a query almost works but it actually concatenates the updated comment onto the end of the old one:

```
UPDATE shared_notes SET json = JSON_SET(json, "$.comments[1]", JSON_MERGE(JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$.comments[1]"), CAST('{"comment":"Test"}' AS JSON) ) ) WHERE note_id = :note_id
```

So is there a better way to easily / dynamically update the JSON using MySQL or is targeting `$.comments[1].comment`, `$.comments[1][0].user_id` etc. the only way?

Comment: Oh man, I just can feel your pain. I can not understand how such a functions is not part of the provided json functions. It's such a basic need!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference [json_merge](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge) has been deprecated since 5.7.22 in favour of [json_merge_preserve](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-preserve) or [json_merge_patch](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch)

so adding to [@Adam Owczarczyk's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47833671/6534484) answer:

```
{...}
select json_merge_preserve('{"comments" : {"comment" : "This is a test comment" }}', comments)
from sampl_test;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but still - you can do it like this:

```
create table sampl_test(id int, comments json);
insert into sampl_test values(1,
'{
    "comments": [
        {
            "comment": "This is a comment",
            "user_id": 5,
            "datecreated": "2016-03-19"
        },
        {
            "comment": "This is a comment",
            "user_id": 1,
            "datecreated": "2016-03-19",
            "comments": [
                {
                    "comment": "This is a sub-comment",
                    "user_id": 4,
                    "datecreated": "2016-03-19"
                },
                {
                    "comment": "This is a sub-comment",
                    "user_id": 4,
                    "datecreated": "2016-03-19"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
')
;

select json_merge('{"comments" : {"comment" : "This is a test comment" }}', comments)

from sampl_test;
```